# Discord Bot (C#) Problems Joining Voice Channel

Tags: c#, discord.net

I have a problem with my bot joining voice channel.

Code:

````
    using Discord;
    using Discord.Commands;
    using Discord.Audio;
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Text;
    using System.Threading.Tasks;

    namespace DodoBot
    {
        class MyBot
        {
            DiscordClient discord;
            CommandService commands;
            Random rand;
            string[] cats = new string[]
            {
                "cate.jpg",
                "gut.jpg",
                "meh.jpg",
                "ugly.jpg",
                "wow.jpg",
            };

            public MyBot()
            {
                rand = new Random();
                discord = new DiscordClient(x =>
                {
                    x.LogLevel = LogSeverity.Info;
                    x.LogHandler = Log;
                });

                discord.UsingCommands(x =>
                {
                    x.PrefixChar = '!';
                    x.AllowMentionPrefix = true;
                });

                commands = discord.GetService<CommandService>();

                RegisterHiCommand();
                RegisterCatdCommand();
                RegisterCatCommand();

                OnJoin();
                OnLeave();

                discord.UsingAudio(x =>
                {
                    x.Mode = AudioMode.Outgoing;
                    RegisterJoinVoiceCommand();
                });

                discord.ExecuteAndWait(async () =>
                {
                    await discord.Connect("MyToken", TokenType.Bot);
                });
            }

            private void RegisterJoinVoiceCommand()
            {
                commands.CreateCommand("summon")
                    .Do(async (e) =>
                    {
                        await e.Channel.SendMessage("```Joining masta!```");
                        await discord.GetService<AudioService>().Join(discord.FindServers("VoiceChannel").FirstOrDefault().VoiceChannels.FirstOrDefault());
                    });
            }

            private void RegisterCatdCommand()
            {
                commands.CreateCommand("catd")
                    .Do(async (e) =>
                    {
                        Message[] msg2Del;
                        msg2Del = await e.Channel.DownloadMessages(1);
                        await e.Channel.DeleteMessages(msg2Del);
                        int imgIndex = rand.Next(cats.Length);
                        await e.Channel.SendFile("Cats/"+cats[imgIndex]);
                    });
            }
            private void RegisterCatCommand()
            {
                commands.CreateCommand("cat")
                    .Do(async (e) =>
                    {
                        int imgIndex = rand.Next(cats.Length);
                        await e.Channel.SendFile("Cats/" + cats[imgIndex]);
                    });
            }
            private void RegisterHiCommand()
            {
                commands.CreateCommand("hi")
                    .Do(async (e) =>
                    {
                        await e.Channel.SendMessage("HelloWorld!");
                    });
            }

            private void OnJoin()
            {
                discord.UserJoined += async (s, e) =>
                {
                    var channel = e.Server.FindChannels("general").FirstOrDefault();
                    var user = e.User.Name;
                    await channel.SendMessage(string.Format("@"+user + " has joined!"));
                };
            }

            private void OnLeave()
            {
                discord.UserLeft += async (s, e) =>
                {
                    var channel = e.Server.FindChannels("general").FirstOrDefault();
                    var user = e.User.Name;
                    await channel.SendMessage(string.Format("@"+user + " has left!"));
                };
            }

            private void Log(object sender, LogMessageEventArgs e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
            }
        }
    }
````

I've done everything like it's written in the documentation [here](http://rtd.discord.foxbot.me/en/legacy/features/voice.html#joining-a-channel).

It executes the SendMessange command but it doesn't join the voice channel.

But Visual Studio says: 
[here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GAJfR.png).

Did I make a mistake?

Thank you for your answers.

Comment: Are you using discord.NET 0.9.4 ? The documentation is for that version.

Comment: No I'm on 0.9.6. But I can't find the documentation for it.

Comment: To be honest I am not so familiar with the audio systems in Discord.NET 0.9.6 , you can seek here at the developers of the API package here : https://discord.gg/JBp6gSN

Comment: Thanks I will check that out.

Answer (score 1):

Does your server called "VoiceChannel"?

If not, than by calling
`discord.FindServers("VoiceChannel")`

your client, most likely, founds nothing (`null`) instead of collection of servers, and tries to fetch voice channels from First() of them

for example, if your server named "My server" and has voice channel named "VoiceChannel" you can use this construction to get your voice channel:
`discord.Servers.Single(s => s.Name == "My server").VoiceChannels.Single(v => v.Name == "VoiceChannel")`

Answer (score 0):

Call this right under your `class myBot`, 
`IVoiceChannel channel;`
 `IAudioClient client;`
Try using this in your music command, if you need more information, I can share my entire Music Module but this should do the trick.

```
IVoiceChannel channel = (Context.User as IVoiceState).VoiceChannel;
IAudioClient client = await channel.ConnectAsync();
```